# prevent sensors from overlapping other bodies

Tags: libgdx, box2d

In libgdx, my actors have box2d bodies which are all implemented as sensors (As i do not want forces to play a role). However, I would like the actors to not overlap one another when they collide.

Basically I would like each actor to treat each other like obstacles and not be able to "overlap" and block on movement on each other (like walking into a wall)

Is this possible in Box2D?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer should be no, since Sensors are explicitly designed not to collide. You could however maybe implement the collision on your own by overwriting BeginContact/EndContact, but actually box2d is doing this quite well. I haven't tried but  maybe it works if you set isSensor to False in BeginContact.

If you want to prevent your objects to not to react on forces, instead of making them a sensor, could you maybe use collision filtering, or set gravity to 0